# How to do these select with select

Tags: subquery, rows

```
Table A, Table B,  Table C
100      A         Honda
200      B         Ferrari 
300      C
400      D
         E  
         F
```

These tables are just for exemple, they don´t have any special meaning!

I am trying to do these

if i do these

```
Select * from A, B, C
```

I will get all combinations, i don't wana that.

I want that the output query to be

```
Col_1  , Col_2,  Col_3
100      A       Honda 
200      B       Ferrari 
300      C       NULL
400      D       NULL
NULL     E       NULL
NULL     F       NULL
```

So what i really want to show the ouput in a single query like above.

Query stupid (`Select * from A, Select * from b, Select * from C`) Ofcorse these will not work...its just to you get the idea

What is the solution to these problem, these must be done in only one query??? 
Thanks

Comment: There is nothing relating those 3 tables together - no primary and foreign keys. Depending on your RDBMS, you could potentially create a row number for each table, then left join from table2 to both table1 and table3.

Comment: But what i wana do is just to List the values of ech table without doing any Cartesian Product at all. These tree tables where suposed to have nothing connectin then like a ID